# set current page url cookie jquery

Tags: jquery, url, cookies, set

How would I set the current page url in a cookie? Right now i'm using `jQuery.cookie("previousUrl", window.location.href, {path:"/"});` but what is being set is the clicked url. How can I set the current page url instead of the clicked url?
Cheers,
Mike

Comment: actually window.location.href is kinda working on my codepen, I am having a similar problem, check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54271468/check-create-render-urls-from-cookie-no-login-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly the answer you were looking for, but have you tried `document.referrer`? On the target page, it should give you the page the user came from, without a need for cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    jQuery.cookie("currentPath", pathName);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi there...thanks for the efforts also. Same results as below.

Comment: at what point are you trying to save the url ? after onClick event ?

Comment: Hi @opensourcelover yes after click event. I'm just trying to save the current page url when a user clicks to open a wordpress post that opens in another page so that when they are done they can go back to the original page.

Comment: why don't you write a cookie ( previousCookie for example) as soon as you enter the page and after going to the next page, read the "previous cookie" and go back to that page ?

Comment: wouldn't that cookie just update when you enter the next page?

Comment: no the idea is, to maintain a cookie that tracks previous pages, you can have another cookie to track current pages, you can manipulate using those two cookies.

Comment: i'm sorry...but can you help with an example?

Comment: Download the jQuery cookie plugin here: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

// setting the cookie
`$.cookie("previousUrl", "www.example.com/page/1");`



// getting the cookie
`alert( $.cookie("previousUrl") );`

Comment: Hi @opensourcelover, yes i've tried this and it just continues to place the current page url in the cookie. If i'm on page2 then click a thumb that opens a post then the previous url is updated with the current page url. I almost need something that will prevent the cookie from updating when an a href is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Download the jQuery cookie plugin here: github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

```
// setting the cookie 

$.cookie("previousUrl", "www.example.com/page/1"); 
$.cookie("currentUrl", "www.example.com/page/2"); 

// getting the cookie 

alert( $.cookie("previousUrl") );

alert( $.cookie("currentUrl") );
```

Maintain those 2 url's and keep updating them as you needed. Now your previousUrl will not interfere with currentUrl.

Comment: Thanks..what happens if there are multiple pages? do I have to set a cookie for multiple pages then?

Comment: You only navigate one page to another at a time. So you can just have just 2 cookies all the time and you have reset them, when you navigate from one page to another. Unless, you are trying to go couple of layers deep like browsers.

Comment: okay..i believe that's my problem. When user navigates to second page they will then click on another link...so that would be a couple of layers then i believe. Still to this point I can't find a solution for this.